# Replace bad values in list with values at same indexes in another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, which are `z` and `w` below:

```
z = [323, 493, 245, 542, 352, 463, 352]
w = [300, -9999, 4343, 320, -9999, -9999, -9999]
```

Now, I need to update the values of `w` by replacing all the `-9999` with the corresponding `z` value. If I were to print `w`, the values would be

```
w = [300, 493, 4343, 320, 352, 463, 352]
```

This is how far I got with the code:

```
w[w == -9999] = z
```

But I get

```
w = [[300, 493, 4343, 320, 352, 463, 352], -9999, 4343, 320, -9999, -9999, -9999]
```

Comment: I don't see files, I see two lists. Also, I suggest you read a Python book or go through the tutorial.

Comment: I can't find anything resembling a duplicate of this; seems like a pretty straightforward problem that we should have a copy of here on the site.

Comment: Do note that the code you have would (almost) work _if_ you were using `numpy.ndarray` instead of `list` objects.  `w[w == -9999] = z[w == -9999]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
z = [323, 493, 245, 542, 352, 463, 352]
w = [300, -9999, 4343, 320, -9999, -9999, -9999]

for index,value in enumerate(w):
    if value == -9999:
        w[index] = z[index]
```

Output

```
[300, 493, 4343, 320, 352, 463, 352]
```

This same idea can be applied within a list comprehension

```
>>> [z[index] if value == -9999 else w[index] for index, value in enumerate(w)]
[300, 493, 4343, 320, 352, 463, 352]
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what is happening in your code as the line is evaluated:

```
w[w == -9999] = z
w[False] = z      # w is a list, so isn't equal to -9999
w[0] = z          # False == 0
```

Hence you replace the first (0th) element in `w` with the list referenced by `z`.

Instead, I think you want:

```
w = [z_val if w_val == -9999 else w_val
     for w_val, z_val in zip(w, z)]
```

Which is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) using the [`zip` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate through pairs of items from `w` and `z`.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no real reason to iterate over two lists or zip them together, you can do it like this - it is faster this way:

```
def replace_values(w, z):
    return [z[num] if x == -9999 else x for num, x in enumerate(w)]
```

Comment: cyber's solution is the fastest

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: It is. I just wrote that it is faster the above way then using zip or iterating over two lists, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use map to do this:

```
>>> z = [323, 493, 245, 542, 352, 463, 352]
>>> w = [300, -9999, 4343, 320, -9999, -9999, -9999]
>>> map(lambda t: t[0] if t[1]==-9999 else t[1], zip(z,w))
[300, 493, 4343, 320, 352, 463, 352]
```

Also natural use for Numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> z = np.array([323, 493, 245, 542, 352, 463, 352])
>>> w = np.array([300, -9999, 4343, 320, -9999, -9999, -9999])
>>> idx=np.where(w==-9999)
>>> w[idx]=z[idx]
>>> w
array([ 300,  493, 4343,  320,  352,  463,  352])
```